# Spring boot. JavaConfig

Tags: java, spring

Здравствуйте, нужна помощь, подсказка, направление.
Имеется Spring boot web.Система отчетов. 
Есть желание по запросу пользователя, выдавать отчет в pdf и exel.

В качестве гайда использую это
[ссылка](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-web-mvc-with-pdf-view-example-using-itext-5x)

Вот, конфигурация происходит с использованием xml.
Нужна подсказка, ссылки, как эту конфигурацию из xml перенести в java config

Comment: вы про `Spring Configuration File`?

Comment: эм, а это зачем вообще делать? Вы хоть понимаете что описано в этом конфигурационном файле, или так  - о круто тут работает нужно все перекинуть и ничего не делать?

Comment: да, про конфигурацию с помощью аннотаций. То что написано в xml понимаю, да и в статье описано.

Comment: я так понимаю надо использовать класс наследник WebMvcConfigurerAdapter ?

Comment: так, удалось получить тестовый pdf, но почему то без данных.

Comment: а пусто было потому что шрифт при который используется в pdf не поддерживал кирилицу я так подозреваю, так как числовые данные отображаются

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot был создан, чтобы не писать на xml. Вот вам конфиг 2-ух бинов:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver defaultViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/jsp");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }


@Bean
    public ViewResolver getCsvViewResolver(){

        ResourceBundleViewResolver resolver = new ResourceBundleViewResolver();
        resolver.setBasename("views");
        resolver.setOrder(1);

        return resolver;
    }
}
```